# Customizing x axis for time series based data using Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, axis

I am new to python programming particularly using Matplotlib. I am currently working on a set of data which I need to plot the x axis using this format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS). I have tried a few methods but with unsuccessful results. My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib import dates as mpl_dates 
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

                         Radio Network Availability Rate(%)  
Time                                                         
2019-10-14 00:00:00                                 99.7144  
2019-10-14 01:00:00                                 99.7144  
2019-10-14 02:00:00                                 99.7144  
2019-10-14 03:00:00                                 99.7144  
2019-10-14 04:00:00                                 99.7144  
...                                                     ...  
2019-10-20 19:00:00                                 99.7403  
2019-10-20 20:00:00                                 99.7403  
2019-10-20 21:00:00                                 99.7404  
2019-10-20 22:00:00                                 99.7403  
2019-10-20 23:00:00                                 99.7403  

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
data['TPG_Radio Network Availability Rate(%)'].plot(style='r.-', title='TPG Network Availability')
plt.ylabel('Availability %')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I would need the output plot to be as below for the x-axis:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below code before `plt.show()`:

```
plt.xticks(len(data.index), data.index)
```

Comment: I tried adding the suggested code but i got the following error:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Answer (score 0):

This helped with what i was looking for:

```
avai = data['TPG_Radio Network Availability Rate(%)']
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,9), dpi=100)
plt.plot(avai, color='r')
plt.ylabel('Availability %')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.title('TPG Network Availability')
loc = plticker.MultipleLocator(base=4.0)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```